# 'NameError: name is not defined' when trying to modify a global variable

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm having an issue when trying to modify a variable in my script with a function.

```
def damage(x):
    """ This function will determine the amount of damage you will take """
    """ hit_c is the chance the enemy has to hit you """
    from random import randint

    global User_HP
    global Enemy_HP

    hit_c = randint(1,5)
    User_damage = randint(1,4)

    if hit_c >= 2:
        Enemy_HP -= User_damage
        lcd_print(textscroll(f"You dealt {User_damage} damage!"))
        lcd_clear()
        lcd_print(textscroll(f"The enemy has {Enemy_HP} HP")
        sleep(1)

    elif hit_c == 1:
            lcd_print("You missed!")

    if Enemy_HP <= 0:
        pass

    else:
        hit_c = randint(1,5)
        Enemy_damage = randint(1,3)

        if hit_c >= 2:
            User_HP -= Enemy_damage
            lcd_print(textscroll(f"You took {Enemy_damage} damage!"))
            lcd_clear()
            lcd_print(User_HP)

        elif hit_c == 1:
            lcd_print(textscroll("The enemy missed!"))
```

The function won't read the global variable Enemy_HP when I try to modify it in this line.

```
Enemy_HP -= User_damage
```

note, I have defined Enemy_HP = 10 at the start of the script.

Help is much appreciated!

Error -

```
File "D:\Desktop\Python Scripts\Lab Project\Lab_Project_Functions.py", line 41, in damage
    Enemy_HP -= User_damage
NameError: name 'Enemy_HP' is not defined`
```

EDIT:
Here is the full code sorry for not including this earlier, I'm also importing several functions

> ```
> from time import sleep
> from random import randint
> from operator import itemgetter
> from engi1020.arduino import *
>
> User_HP = 10
> Enemy_HP = 10
>
>
> wait_1 = True
> def loading(wait_time):
>     if wait_1 == True:
>         sleep(1)
>         lcd_clear()
>         lcd_print('.')
>         sleep(1)
>         lcd_clear()
>         lcd_print('..')
>         sleep(1)
>         lcd_clear()
>         lcd_print('...')
>         sleep(1)
>         lcd_clear()
>         lcd_print('.')
>         sleep(1)
>         lcd_clear()
>         lcd_print('..')
>         sleep(1)
>         lcd_clear()
>         lcd_print('...')
>         sleep(1)
>         lcd_clear()
>
> inventory = []
>
> from Lab_Project_Functions import *
>
> #Get some basic gameplay information
> lcd_print("starting the game")
> lcd_clear()
> loading(wait_1)
>
> lcd_print(textscroll("Hello!, What speed would you like the dialogue to play at? ('slow, normal, fast')"))
> Dia_Spd = input()
> if Dia_Spd == "slow":
>     DiaSpd = 4
> elif Dia_Spd == "normal":
>     DiaSpd = 3
> elif Dia_Spd == "fast":
>     DiaSpd = 2
> elif Dia_Spd == "test":
>     DiaSpd = 0
>
> lcd_clear()
> lcd_print()
> loading(wait_1)
> '''
> name = input("What is your name?")
> class_ = "Knight"
>
> sleep(1)
> class_ = input("Which class is befitting you young adventurer?"
>                 " A noble 'Knight'?"
>                 " A Studious 'Wizard'?"
>                 " Or a Mystifying 'Warlock'?")
> '''
>
> loading(wait_1)
>
> #lcd_print(f"What ho {class_} {name}, welcome to the game!!")
> lcd_print(textscroll("What ho brave knight, welcome to the game!!"))
> sleep(DiaSpd)
> lcd_clear()
>
> lcd_print(textscroll("Let's start with a some basics"))
> sleep(DiaSpd)
> lcd_clear()
> #Start by creating a basic combat system.
>
> lcd_print(textscroll("An enemy approaches you! Learn to fight!"))
> sleep(DiaSpd)
> lcd_clear()
>
> #Create more combat elements.
>
> while User_HP > 0:
>     lcd_print(textscroll("Pick a fighting option."))
>     lcd_print("FIGHT--ITEM--DEF")
>     fight_option = input()
>
>     if fight_option == 'FIGHT' or 'fight' or 'Fight':
>         damage(1)
>
>     elif fight_option == 'ITEM' or 'item' or 'Item':
>         item_pickup(1)
>
>     else:
>         defend(1)
>
>     if Enemy_HP <= 0:
>         lcd_print(textscroll("THE ENEMY WAS SLAIN!"))
>         break
>
>     sleep(DiaSpd)
>
> lcd_print(textscroll("Good job you're learning the basics!"))
> sleep(DiaSpd)
> lcd_print(textscroll("To reward you for your efforts, here is an item that the enemy dropped!"))
> sleep(DiaSpd)
> item_pickup(1)
>
> #remember to redefine enemy hp before next fight
>
> lcd_print(textscroll("Hi ho yee noble knight, welcome to your humble abode. You can perform all sorts of actions here."))
> sleep(DiaSpd)
> lcd_clear()
> lcd_print(textscroll("What would you like to do?"))
> sleep(DiaSpd)
> lcd_clear()
> lcd_print(textscroll("Look through inventory----Rest (Heal)----Go adventuring"))
> home_option = input() #change this to accept input from button & joystick
>
> while True:
>     if home_option == 1:
>         pass
>     if home_option == 2:
>         pass
>     if home_option == 3:
>         pass
> ```

the function imports are from here

```
from engi1020.arduino import *

#Looting // Item Pickup Function def item_pickup(enemy_num):
    """ This Function will determine the items the user picks up """
    '''
    enemy_num is the variable deciding which enemy you are fighting
    '''
    from random import randint
    rand_item = randint(1,4)
    global inventory

    if enemy_num == 1:
        if rand_item <= 3:
            inventory.append('IRON_SWORD')
            print(textscroll("You picked up the IRON SWORD!"))

        elif rand_item == 4:
            inventory.append('STEELY_VENGANCE')
            lcd_print(textscroll("You found a rare item! 'STEELY VENGANCE' was added to your inventory!"))
        else:
            'no item found'
    if enemy_num == 2:
        pass

#Combat Function def damage(x):
    """ This function will determine the amount of damage you will take """
    """ hit_c is the chance the enemy has to hit you """
    from random import randint

    global User_HP
    global Enemy_HP

    hit_c = randint(1,5)
    User_damage = randint(1,4)

    if hit_c >= 2:
        Enemy_HP -= User_damage
        lcd_print(textscroll(f"You dealt {User_damage} damage!"))
        lcd_clear()
        lcd_print(textscroll(f"The enemy has {Enemy_HP} HP")
        sleep(1)

    elif hit_c == 1:
            lcd_print("You missed!")

    if Enemy_HP <= 0:
        pass

    else:
        hit_c = randint(1,5)
        Enemy_damage = randint(1,3)

        if hit_c >= 2:
            User_HP -= Enemy_damage
            lcd_print(textscroll(f"You took {Enemy_damage} damage!"))
            lcd_clear()
            lcd_print(User_HP)

        elif hit_c == 1:
            lcd_print(textscroll("The enemy missed!"))

#Item Select Function def item_select(item_number):
    from operator import itemgetter

    while True:
        lcd_print(textscroll("What item would you like to use?"))
        lcd_clear()
        sleep(1)
        lcd_print(textscroll("note you need to select items numerically, i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3,...,etc. "))
        lcd_clear()
        sleep(1)
        lcd_print(textscroll(inventory))
        item_choice = int(input())
        lcd_clear()
        lcd_print("Which item?:")
        num_items = len(inventory)
        if item_choice < num_items:
            item = itemgetter(item_choice)(inventory)
            if item == potion:
                global User_HP
                User_HP += 5
                lcd_print(User_HP)
                break
        else:
            lcd_print(textscroll("ERROR! ITEM CHOICE IS AN INVALID OPTION!"))

#Defend Function def defend(User):
    Enemy_damage = randint(1,3)
    lcd_print(textscroll(f"The user blocked {Enemy_damage} damage"))

#Text Scrolling Function def textscroll(text):
    from time import sleep

    i = 0
    j = 15
    while True:
        lcd_print(text[i:j])
        i += 1
        j += 1
        sleep(0.2)
        lcd_clear()
        if j >= len(text) + 15:
            break
```

Comment: please fix your indentation. In any case, you should always avoid mutable global state to begin with. i.e. *don't modify global variables*, and use global variables sparingly.

Comment: Where do you actually give `Enemy_HP` a value?

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] which means fixing the code indenting and including the definition of `Enemy_HP`.

Comment: Anyway, no where in this code is `Enemy_HP` defined. Why do you think it *should* be defined? Can you point to where you defined it? Note, you really must provide a [mcve]. This code does nothing if I run it, because it merely defined a function.

Comment: I give the Enemy_HP value right at the beginning of the script before the function is even defined.
also i noticed the indentation it didn't copy over correctly into the post.

Comment: @Random The main reason that we're asking for an MRE is that, in this code, `Enemy_HP` simply isn't defined. You need to give us code that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Are multiple modules being imported here? "global" really means "current module namespace" if `Enemy_HP` is defined in one module its not "global" in a different module.

Comment: You will have the most success if the example is pared down to a minimum example. For something like this a dozen lines of code, max. All we care about for this question is a trivial use of `Enemy_HP` demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @tdelaney I didn't realize global variables didn't work the same when using another module, I think i can fix the issue now, thanks for the tip.
I'll remember to keep it the code to the minimum from now on.

Comment: @RandomRules - I'm not happy with the keyword being "global" but I haven't come up with anything better! It fits well with what the `globals()` function does - gets the module namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you have is because you didn't assign a value to it (even tho you said):

> exception **NameError**: Raised when a local or global name is not found. This applies only to unqualified names. The associated value is an error message that includes the name that could not be found.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#bltin-exceptions

---

The problem in your code is that you are **trying to access variables from one file without importing them**. 
Global variables only exist inside the file they are defined.
Just import them like they were functions:

```
import Enemy_HP
```